# "Object does not support this property or method" but works in separate function

Tags: excel, vba

I have this function called when the user clicks a button. It is supposed to open up a new sheet (if it doesn't already exist), add a listbox, and add values to it. It does a lot more but I removed a lot of code for the sake of posting on here, but made sure it throws the same error. If you see some minor error it is only because I truncated it incorrectly or changed variable names.

The problem is that is throws the error "Object does not support this property or method error" at the line:

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FFL").xxx.AddItem "hi"

I have tried calling it in another function from this function and I still get the same error. **When I copy and paste this same line into a separate function and run it separately after the sheet is created it works just fine.**

I have tried variations like fffl.xxx.AddItem Item:="hi", list.AddItem "hi"

I've tried everything

```
Public Sub Test()
If sheetExists("FFL") Then

MsgBox ("Only one FFL session can be open at a time.")

Else

pmsID = Application.Caller
Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FFL Calendar"))
sheet.Name = "FFL"
Set fffl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FFL")

Dim list As Object
Set t = fffl.Range("B7")
Set list = fffl.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1", Left:=t.Left, Top:=t.Top, Width:=t.Width * 2, Height:=t.Height * 5)
list.Name = "xxx"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FFL").xxx.AddItem "hi"
```

Comment: There is no such method as .xxx for the Worksheets object.

Comment: why are you not using `list.additem "hi"`?

Comment: You have already set the new list to `list`. Have you tried `list.AddItem "hi"`?

Comment: it takes some time for the xxx name to propagate. If you add a DoEvents after setting the name, it should work

Comment: Sorry @VincentG, didn't see your comment before posting mine :)

Comment: Same with FFL, you already have a reference to the sheet (sheet, which is a bad name IMO), so why are you getting a new one?

Comment: @SuperSymmetry no harm done ;)

Comment: I appreciate the quick responses but I wrote in my initial post that have tried list.AddItem "hi". I will look into DoEvents. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the line `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FFL").xxx.AddItem "hi"` with

```
list.Object.AddItem "hi"
```

The `.OLEObjects.Add` method returns an `OLEObject` object, which doesn't have an `AddItem` method. However, its `.Object` property returns the actual underlying object, which is a `ListBox` in this case: Polymorphism at its best and most confusing :)

Comment: This worked! Partly... It works when I run the code right after I create the list box, but if I try it further down in the sub it gives the same error. I also still don't understand why when I called it from a separate sub it doesn't need this object property. I'll look into it more but I'm on the right track.

Comment: Would you kindly elaborate. What worked and what didn't work. Thanks

Comment: It is not working directly after going into a for loop:
`   
RowCount = SN.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To RowCount
       list.Object.AddItem "hi"
    Next i
`
It's throwing the same error

Comment: I added your loop and it worked well for me. Please update your question to add lines up to and including the loop. To be able to help you I need to see what is happening until you enter the loop

Comment: If you cannot update the question, are you able to share the file so someone can have a look?

Comment: If **all** list items are actually in the range, then you don't need to loop to add items. `OLEObject`s happen to have a `ListFillRange` property that you can use. You can simply replace your loop with `list.ListFillRange = SN.Name & "!A3:A" & RowCount`. However, after setting this property, you cannot use `AddItem`. You should use either one of them, but you cannot use both of them at the same time.

Comment: This is something I am building for work with semi-sensitive information so I would rather not share it in its entirety. I ended up moving the loop to just underneath the section where I created the listbox and it is working fine now. The AddItem line worked all down the sub until I put it in a For loop. But once I put it just below the creation of the listbox it works in the for loop. So many things about this still doesn't make sense but I can't put any more energy/ effort into this. I'm using what I've got now and moving on. Thanks for the help.